# Passing Parameter Files for CloudFormation Does Not Work with YML

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, devops

**Solution**: Don't use yml.

I'm trying to pass parameters that hold the db name and the db password along with my `aws cloudformation stack-create` command. I get back an error that doesn't make a whole lot of sense.

```
Value of property MasterUsername must be of type String
```

Now, one thing to know is that I have console access so I can literally see the password and username come back in the console as what was set. They both look like strings to me.

**YAML Version**

I'm defining the stack in a template like this:

```
Parameters:
  DBUser:
    Description: db user
    Type: String
    MinLength: '4'
    MaxLength: '16'
    AllowedPattern: '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*'
    ConstraintDescription: some description
  DBPass:
    Description: db password
    Type: String
    MinLength: '8'
    MaxLength: '36'
    AllowedPattern: '[a-zA-Z0-9]*'
    ConstraintDescription: must contain only alphanumeric characters
Resources:
  AppNode:
   (...)
  DatabaseInstance:
    Type: AWS::RDS::DBInstance
    Properties:
      DBName: app
      DBInstanceClass: db.t2.micro
      Engine: postgres
      EngineVersion: 10
      MasterUsername:
        - !Ref DBUser
      MasterUserPassword:
        - !Ref DBPass
  DatabaseSG:
    Type: AWS::RDS::DBSecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: Security Group for RDS public access
      DBSecurityGroupIngress:
        - CIDRIP: 0.0.0.0/0
```

Inside of my `.env` file I have this:

```
[
  {
    "ParameterKey": "DBUser",
    "ParameterValue": "root"
  },
  {
    "ParameterKey": "DBPass",
    "ParameterValue": "mydbpassword"
  }
]
```

I run this command:

```
aws cloudformation create-stack --stack-name app --template-body file://$PWD/stack.json --region us-west-2 --parameters file://$PWD/.env.json
```

for the file type.

So the first thing that comes to mind is that maybe it's getting those values as blank.  That can't be the case though because if I don't pass a template or parameters at all it, throws a different error.

```
An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the CreateStack operation: Parameters: [DBUser, DBPass] must have values
```

Did AWS redefine what a string is or what is going on here?

Comment: Could you show the actual Json stack your using since your not executing this command in YML?

Answer (score 1):

Correct your template as below.

```
Resources:
  AppNode:
   (...)
  DatabaseInstance:
    Type: AWS::RDS::DBInstance
    Properties:
      DBName: app
      DBInstanceClass: db.t2.micro
      Engine: postgres
      EngineVersion: 10
      MasterUsername:
        !Ref DBUser
      MasterUserPassword:
        !Ref DBPass
```

When you use `- !Ref DBUser`, it signifies a `LIST` in yaml, not `String`. 
`MasterUserPassword` and `MasterUserPassword` are both of type `String`.
AWS supports both `.yml` and `.yaml` extensions. So there is no issue with you extensions.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to say that external parameters are not supported via file for yaml files.

You can pass them in command line as a workaround.

**Reference:**

https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/2275

There is still in work in progress.

Hope it helps.

**EDIT1:**

```
      MasterUsername:
        - ${DBUser}
      MasterUserPassword:
        - ${DBPass}
```

Looks like your YAML syntax is not correct.

Reference:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/quickref-general.html

Comment: Thanks for the link!  I've tried using command line like this: `aws cloudformation create-stack --stack-name app --template-body file://$PWD/stack.yml --region us-west-2 --parameters ParameterKey=DBUser,ParameterValue=root ParameterKey=DBPass,ParameterValue=pleasegodletmein`. But I get the same error.  Should I just ditch yml altogether?

Comment: Only thing I found difference between mine and yours the extension of the file. used, yaml. But json is fully supported, yaml is still fully on complete support yet.

Comment: My parameter file has a `json` extension. Do you mean they don't support yml at all?

Comment: ${DBPass} format works only in !Sub, it won't work as just parameter.

Answer (score 0):

> MasterUsername must be of type String

Here you have a list (array), not string:

```
MasterUsername:
        - !Ref DBUser
```

Use on the same line instead:

```
MasterUsername: !Ref DBUser
```